# Is the result of Window.getComputedStyle() always up-to-date?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

[`Window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) returns a `CSSStyleDeclaration` object with the resolved style properties of an element.

Is this object kept up-to-date as the page changes? For example, is this guaranteed to work?

```
var style = window.getComputedStyle(myDiv);
assert(myDiv.display == 'block');
myDiv.style.display = 'none';
assert(myDiv.style.display == 'none'); // Magically updated
```

I've noticed that the objects returned by calling `getComputedStyle()` are not equal to each other. I assumed you couldn't cache the result of `getComputedStyle()` since it's read-only. Will accessing properties always return the latest resolved value?

```
var style1 = window.getComputedStyle(myDiv);
myDiv.style.display = 'none';
var style2 = window.getComputedStyle(myDiv);
assert(style1 != style2);  // Not the same object
for (var i = 0; i < style1.length; i++)
  assert(style1[i] == style2[i]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [CSS Object Model](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-1/#extensions-to-the-window-interface), [`getComputedStyle`](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-1/#dom-window-getcomputedstyle) is defined as

> ```
> partial interface Window {
>   [NewObject] CSSStyleDeclaration getComputedStyle(
>     Element elt,
>     optional DOMString? pseudoElt
>   );
> };
> ```

Effectively, each time you call it, you get a different object. That's because of [`[NewObject]`](http://heycam.github.io/webidl/#NewObject):

> If the [`[NewObject]`](http://heycam.github.io/webidl/#NewObject) [extended attribute](http://heycam.github.io/webidl/#dfn-extended-attribute) appears on a
>   [regular](http://heycam.github.io/webidl/#dfn-regular-operation) or [static](http://heycam.github.io/webidl/#dfn-static-operation) [operation](http://heycam.github.io/webidl/#dfn-operation), then it indicates that
>   when calling the operation, a reference to a newly created object MUST
>   always be returned.

However, the returned declaration must be live:

> Return a live CSS declaration block with the following properties:
>
> - [readonly flag](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-1/#cssstyledeclaration-readonly-flag): Set.
> - [declarations](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-1/#cssstyledeclaration-declarations): All longhand properties that are [supported CSS properties](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-1/#supported-css-property), in lexicographical order, with the value being the [resolved value](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-1/#resolved-value) computed for obj using the style rules associated with *doc*.
> - [parent CSS rule](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-1/#cssstyledeclaration-parent-css-rule): Null.
> - [owner node](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-1/#cssstyledeclaration-owner-node): *obj*.

The spec doesn't explicitly define what "live" means, but I guess it's reasonable enough.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking in DOM-Level-2-Style which is what MDN cited.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. `getComputedStyle` returns a [`live`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList#A_sometimes-live_collection) collection of CSS properties.

Each time the `getComputedStyle` method is called a *new* object is returned and 2 objects are not considered equal in JavaScript, i.e.:

```
getComputedStyle(el) === getComputedStyle(el) // false
```

Just like `{} === {} // false`. The properties of the collection is updated whenever the styles of the related element is changed. This means the computed property values of the 2 `CSSStyleDeclaration` objects are equal but the 2 objects themselves are not equal.

```
cssStyleDeclaration1.color === cssStyleDeclaration2.color // true
```

The above code snippet returns true as it compares 2 strings (primitive values).